# How to simply store signed, hashed data on Tezos blockchain?

Tags: smart-contracts, taquito, storage, api, blockchain

I'm new to Tezos. I'm wanting to store some signed, hashed data on the Tezos blockchain, most likely using Taquito/Batch API. Can anyone direct me to the correct method to simply send the data and get back the hashed transaction information. I want the transaction data so I can look up the stored data later. Is it just the `send` method from here: https://tezostaquito.io/docs/batch_api/#how-does-it-work ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will store the information in a smart contract.

`(await <...>.send()).hash` will give you the operation hash.

In this [example](https://tezostaquito.io/docs/smartcontracts#calling-the-increment-function) you can click `Run code` to obtain the operation hash.

Comment: I will try this, thank you